# problem with decleration of more than one instance

Tags: python

hellow im write the code above :

```
class val:

    def __init__(self, value, TYPE):
        val.value = value
        val.TYPE = TYPE

u = val([1, -3], 'polar')
v = val([0, 2], 'cartesian')

print(u.value)
print(u.TYPE)
print(v.value)
print(v.TYPE)
```

but the output is :

```
[0, 2]
cartesian
[0, 2]
cartesian
```

why the first instance has changed (I expected to get [1, -3] in the first row)

Comment: Because you are referencing `val` in your `__init__()` instead of `self`.

Comment: Simply change `val.value = value` to `self.value = value` and `val.TYPE = TYPE` to `self.TYPE = TYPE`.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the class where you should be referring to the object passed to `__init__`. As a result you repeatedly change the values of two *class* attributes, rather than setting *instance* attributes on separate instances.

```
class val:

    def __init__(self, value, TYPE):
        self.value = value
        self.TYPE = TYPE
```

---

A couple of conventions:

1. User-defined classes are capitalized
2. To avoid shadowing a built-in name, append a `_` to the name.

   ```
   class Val:
       def __init__(self, value, type_):
           self.value = value
           self.type = type_
   ```

(You can use `type` as an attribute name without shadowing the built-in name `type`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "val.value" to "self.value", etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it changed is because you used the class name **val** and set its fields instead of the object itself. **val** refers to the class. Use **self** to refer to an instance of this class.

Code fix;

```
def __init__(self, value, TYPE):
    self.value = value
    self.TYPE = TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned your variables to the class `val`, not the instance `self`. In python, an instance lookup falls back to the class if the variable isn't there. Your second instance creation overwrote the class level variables and your later references to the instance fell back to that overwritten value. Use the `self` instance reference instead.

```
class val:

    def __init__(self, value, TYPE):
        self.value = value
        self.TYPE = TYPE

u = val([1, -3], 'polar')
v = val([0, 2], 'cartesian')

print(u.value)
print(u.TYPE)
print(v.value)
print(v.TYPE)
```